# Not sure how to pass the id of an image so I can use it in my ajax call

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel

Currently, I am trying to implement voting system so users can like or dislike uploaded images, however, I'm trying to do it with an ajax call which makes it a bit confusing for me. I am not sure how to pass the id of the image the user is liking (there are going to be plenty of images on the page) to the ajax call. In the JavaScript file, the data: imageId is currently empty since I don't know how exactly to determine and pass the id of the image.

Home view:

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')
    @foreach($images as $image)
        <div class='imageContainer'>
            <div class="stickyContainer blackGradient">
                <h1 class='imageTitle'>{{$image->name}}</h1>
                <img class='uploadedImg' src='{{url("storage/uploads/images/".$image->file_name)}}' alt='Random image'/>
                <a class='specialA' href='{{url("image/".$image->id)}}'></a>
                <div class='votingContainer'>
                    <a href='#'><div class='like'></div></a>
                    <a href='#'><div class='dislike'></div></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    @endforeach
    <script>
        var token = '{{ Session:token() }}';
        var urlLike = '{{ route('like') }}';
    </script>
@endsection
```

JavaScript File:

```
$('.like').on('click', function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var isLike = event.target.previousElementSibling == null;
        console.log(isLike);
        $.ajax({
            method: 'POST',
            url: urlLike,
            data: {isLike: isLike, imageId: , _token: token}
        })
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign image's id to the like button in the view:

```
 <a href='#'><div class='like' id={{$image->id)}}></div></a>
```

Then, in javascript use image's id to the ajax call.

```
 imageId= event.target.id;
```

On a side note: In javascript I don't understand why you are nulling the previousSibling with this:

```
var isLike = event.target.previousElementSibling == null;
```

Answer (score 0):

Add Data attribute with attribute value as image Id to image element like `data-imgId="1"`.It should be unique for each image element.

```
<img class='uploadedImg' src='{{url("storage/uploads/images/".$image->file_name)}}' data-imgId="{{$image->id)}}" alt='Random image'/>
```

Then get the image Id by using below script

```
var imgId = $(this).parents('.stickyContainer').find('.uploadedImg').attr('data-imgId');
```